# Loop through objects properties in an object

Tags: c#, .net, loops, object, reflection

I have got an object like below

```
public class MainObj 
{
    public int BankDetailPercentage { get; set; }
    public int PersonalDetailPercentage { get; set; }
    public BankDetail BankDetail { get; set; }
    public PersonalDetail PersonalDetail { get; set; }
}
public class BankDetail
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Branch { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
}
public class PersonalDetail
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
}
```

I need to loop through that MainObj Object and find how many properties of BankDetail and PersonalDetail objects are filled and on the basis of that I should set the percentage of filled properties in MainObj object's BankDetailPercentage and PersonalDetailPercentage fields and return it. How can I accomplish this, I have tried below but couldn't get how to do it

```
    public MainObject calculatePercentage(MainObject mainObject) 
    {
        int bdCount = 0, pdCount = 0, bdTotal = 3, pdTotal = 2;

        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(MainObject).GetProperties();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var value = property.GetValue(mainObject);
            if (property.Name == "BankDetail")
            {
              //
            }
        }
        return mainObject;
    }
```

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to use Reflection for this task instead of simply checking the individual values of each BankDetail and PersonalDetail?

Comment: @AndrewH Not really, but the thing is that this MainObj has many similar objects like BankDetail and PersonalDetail with lots of properties, checking the individual values would be very tedious I suppose.

Comment: Reflection should be reserved for special cases since it has performance implications that checking each individual property (while tedious) does not. I think you will spend more time writing code with reflection to attempt to solve your problem and create future tech debt when your data contract changes and you have confusing reflection code to update. The simple solution is taking the time to check for the values you really care about not being null, or add additional properties that track whether all required values have been populated and those values can simply be checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will need to get the instance of the object in question (which you have done in your code above.

```
var value = property.GetValue(mainObject);
```

Then you need to count how many properties are contained in that object.  To do that we need to first get the properties.

```
var subProperties = property.PropertyType.GetProperties();
var propertyCount = subProperties.Length;
```

Now we need to check each of those properties to see if a value is set.

```
var populatedCount = 0;

foreach (var subProperty in subProperties)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(subProperty.GetValue(value)))
    {
        populatedCount++;
    }
}
```

Then take the percentage.

```
var percentage = (float)populatedCount / propertyCount;
```

Comment: Excellent it worked like a charm, I used "property.PropertyType.BaseType.Name" to check if its an object I am dealing with, thanks a million :)

Comment: Happy to help.  In addition to comparing by name, you could also check if the type is the type you are referring to via  `if (property.PropertyType is MyType)`  ex. `if (property.PropertyType is BankDetail)`  that way you are not tied to a specific naming in your classes that use these classes.

Comment: Shouldn't I just use `if (property.PropertyType.IsClass)` to check if it's an object and only then proceed with checking subProperties?

Comment: I was suggesting instead of using a string comparison of the name, you could use the type in question (ex. BankDetails) and the property type.  There is technically no difference at the moment, but if you had named the property differently or changed its name, the string comparison would fail while a type check would not.  No harm in what you are currently doing, just not as fail safe.

Comment: As for `IsClass`, you could use that but will still have to do a type check or name comparison, so in the end it wouldn't really accomplish anything.   The overhead with reflection is already high, small micro optimizations won't matter much (unless in a tight loop)